# Checking If File Exists Based On Start Of File Name Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that checks if a file exists in a folder.  This works fine but I have discovered that the files when they are saved have extra characters added to the filename as these are based on date and time the file was created.

**1r81812-W3TAGPW6-Success-2022-05-10-12-11-13** is the full file name example, I only care about the first part before the first hyphen.

Is there anyway to use my script to only search the first part of the file name to see if the file exists?

```
    Sub CheckIfFileExists()

   Dim LRow As Integer
   Dim LPath As String
   Dim LExtension As String
   Dim LContinue As Boolean

   LContinue = True
   LRow = 2
   LPath = "Z:\Wiping\ToBeProcessed\"
   LExtension = ".pdf"

   'Loop through all column A values until a blank cell is found
   While LContinue

Found a blank cell, do not continue
      If Len(Range("A" & CStr(LRow)).Value) = 0 Then
         LContinue = False

      'Check if file exists for part number
      Else
         'Place "No" in column B if the file does NOT exist
         If Len(Dir(LPath & Range("A" & CStr(LRow)).Value & LExtension)) = 0 Then
            Range("B" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "No"
            'Place "Yes" in column B if the file does exist
         Else
            Range("B" & CStr(LRow)).Value = "Yes"
         End If
      End If

      LRow = LRow + 1

   Wend
```

Comment: Looks by your code that you are trying to check some cells with a file name if they exists on the folder? I would use `FileSystemObject` to loop through the files in the folder and check if they exist in my cells with `MyFile.Name Like Cell.Value & "*" & LExtension`

Comment: The cells of column A contains the part that you are looking for, like `1r81812`?

Comment: Yes the first part of the file name is in A2 and I just want to ignore the remaining parts of the file name.

Comment: Add a wildcard to the `Dir()` call - `If Len(Dir(LPath & Range("A" & CStr(LRow)).Value & "*" & LExtension)) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

This code should get the job done:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckIfFileExists()
    
    'first, store your cell values in a dictionary
    'for this to work, go to menu tools-references-check the library: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    'change SheetName for the sheet name where the partial file names are stored
    Dim arr_file_names As Variant: arr_file_names = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").UsedRange.Value
    Dim files_to_check As Dictionary: Set files_to_check = load_files_to_check(arr_file_names)
    
    'Create a FSO object  to loop through  the files in a folder
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim my_folder As Folder: Set my_folder = fso.GetFolder("Z:\Wiping\ToBeProcessed\")
    Dim my_file As File
    Dim LExtension As String: LExtension = ".pdf"
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim file_row As Long
    'loop through all the files in the folder
    For Each my_file In my_folder.Files
        file_name = LCase(my_file.Name)
        If file_name Like "*" & LExtension Then
            'get the first part of the file name before the first "-"
            file_name = Split(file_name, "-")(0)
            If files_to_check.Exists(file_name) Then
                file_row = files_to_check(file_name)
                arr_file_names(file_row, 2) = "Yes"
            End If
        End If
    Next my_file
    
    'this will only output the files that the code has found you could now iterate over the array
    'to fill the files not found with "No"
    For file_row = 2 To UBound(arr_file_names)
        If arr_file_names(file_row, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For
        If arr_file_names(file_row, 2) <> "Yes" Then arr_file_names(file_row, 2) = "No"
    Next file_row
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").UsedRange.Value = arr_file_names
    
End Sub
Private Function load_files_to_check(arr As Variant) As Dictionary
    
    'Init the dictionary
    Set load_files_to_check = New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    'loop through the data in the worksheet stored inside an array
    'that's faster than working with the sheet
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        'like in your code, the code will stop upon finding a blank cell in column A
        If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For
        'store the file name (in lower case) and it's row position
        load_files_to_check.Add LCase(arr(i, 1)), i
    Next i

End Function
```